# Setting attribute of Image Object jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an Image object as following:

```
var img_BlinkingGreen = new Image();
img_BlinkingGreen.src = "Images/UIFiles/transparent-area.gif";
```

I want to set attributes of image object and a class and a click event. How can I do that?
I am doing like this but it is giving me an error

```
  img_BlinkingGray.attr({
                            position: "absolute",
                            opacity: ".1",
                            height: height,
                            width: width,
                            left: left,
                            top: top,
                            class: lnk_question
                        }).onclick("GoToStep('" + nextAns + "');");
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No-one has posted the right answer.

- You have to use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set styles,
- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set attributes.
- To set an onclick handler with a specific parameter, you can use [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) + [`.attr("data-nextAns")`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (or [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), if your jQuery version supports it).

Code:

```
  var img_BlinkingGray = $("<img">).css({
        position: "absolute",
        opacity: ".1",
        height: height,
        width: width,
        left: left,
        top: top
    }).attr({
        class: lnk_question,
        src: "Images/UIFiles/transparent-area.gif",
        "data-nextAns": nextAns
    }).click(function(){
        GoToStep($(this).attr("nextAns"));
    });
//To append the image, you can use something like this:
img_BlinkingGray.appendTo("body");
```

Comment: I wanted to create a image on page load and letter i wanted to use it at different location. when i will created image as you have suggested will a request for the image on the server. My purpose of declaring image at the starting of the script that other time I only change the attribute of the image. Not create a whole new image. I have read about preloaded images. I wanted to do that.

Comment: So, what exactely do you want? Only load an image? What's up with the styles, classnames and click handler? How does that relate to preloading?

Comment: let me explain bit more. I have a page divided into two parts. I part contain Images and other part a table with at least 20 <b>td</b> depending on the database values. when user click on <b>td</b> or on the image the position of image get change may be number of images will also change. The style is for that purpose. class name is for some static values. The purpose of my application is to create mobile like visuals. Means on the left mobile is displayed and on the right script is displayed. script says click on mobile setting then setting screen opens.

Comment: so each time user click on any script or td imge position get change. and If i follow your suggestion it wll request server for image. Will not be it a good idea to create a imge at page load and place the image accordingly.

Comment: Now, to the point: What **exactely** do you expect from the answer? What should technically happen with hte (preloaded) image? Preloading an image will only cause the image to be directly visible when the `<img>` tag is appended. Creating multiple `<img>` elements with the same `src` attribute will only cause one request to the server, provided that it's not misconfigured.

Comment: when ever user will click on td or image will not a new request for image will go to the server? Because the setting is done inside the click event. I want to avoid that. Am I going to the right direction or not?

Comment: @krshekhar See my previous comment. If an image has already been loaded, it does not matter if you're creating a new `<img>` element with the same `src`, *provided that your server is not misconfigured.*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6258/discussion-between-krshekhar-and-rob-w)

Answer (score 1):

`img_BlinkingGreen` is not a jQuery object until you cast it as one.

```
$(img_BlinkingGray).attr({
                        position: "absolute",
                        opacity: ".1",
                        height: height,
                        width: width,
                        left: left,
                        top: top,
                        class: lnk_question
                    }).click(function(){ GoToStep(nextAns); });
```

Should work :)

edit: noticed your click handler is funky too.  Try the individual jQuery commands one by one if you're still having problems.

Comment: I wanted to create a image on page load and letter i wanted to use it at different location. when i will created image as you have suggested will a request for the image on the server. My purpose of declaring image at the starting of the script that other time I only change the attribute of the image. Not create a whole new image. I have read about preloaded images. I wanted to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use jQuery functions on jQuery objects. Create your image like so:

```
$("<img>")
    .attr({
        'src': 'Images/UIFiles/transparent-area.gif',
        // modify all the other attributes here too
    })
    .click(function(){
        // jquery uses click, not onclick
    });
```

Though it is generally recommended to use `bind()`, `delegate()`, or `on()` for event handling. `on()` was added in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @m90: I *honestly* have no idea why I did that.

Comment: I am modifying my question please have a look. because src is not working.

Comment: I wanted to create a image on page load and letter i wanted to use it at different location. when i will created image as you have suggested will a request for the image on the server. My purpose of declaring image at the starting of the script that other time I only change the attribute of the image. Not create a whole new image. I have read about preloaded images. I wanted to do that.